# Puppet: Error: Could not run: Could not find file manifests/web01.pp

Tags: puppet

I am new user of Puppet and I created my web01.pp file to do following tasks.

1. install nginx server
2. configure nginx server
3. copying my already created index file from one directory to another directory in client machine
4. add user with sudo privileges

---

my web01 files looks like

```
    node 'web01.example.com' {
  package { 'apache2.2-common':
    ensure => absent,
  }
  package { 'nginx':
    ensure => installed,
    require => Package['apache2.2-common'],
  }
  service { 'nginx':
    ensure => running,
    require => Package['nginx'],
  }
exec { 'mkdir -p /var/www/web01':
    command => '/bin/mkdir -p /var/www/web01'
}
exec { 'cp -rf /root/site/index.php /var/www/web01/':
    command => '/bin/cp -rf /root/site/index.php /var/www/web01/'
}
   file { "/var/www/web01":
           source => "puppet:///files/web01.conf",
           notify => Service['nginx'],
}

user { 'newuser':
    # (namevar) The user name
    name      => 'newuser',  
    # The user's status: 'present','absent','role'
    ensure    => 'present',
    # Eventual user's secondary groups (use array for many)
    groups    => [ 'sudo' ],
    # The user's password. As it appears in /etc/shadow
    # Use single quotes to avoid unanted evaluation of $* as variables
    # Typical users' attributes
    shell     => '/bin/bash',
    home      => '/home/newuser',
    sshkeytype => "ssh-rsa",
    sshkey     => "AAAA..."

}

}
```

after that I created

> /etc/puppet/files/web01.conf

and use these commands

> puppet apply manifests/web01.pp

and get this error

```
Error: Could not run: Could not find file manifests/web01.pp
```

Is there anything I missed or to configure to apply ?

Comment: Did you check the Puppet apply [examples](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/man/apply.html#EXAMPLE)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the following then make sure you are in manifests directory before you run the puppet apply command:

```
file { "/var/www/web01":
       source => "puppet:///files/web01.conf",
       notify => Service['nginx'],
```

you declared /var/www/web01 as a dir earlier then you tried to create file with the same name

fix:

```
file { "/var/www/web01/web01.conf":
       source => "puppet:///files/web01.conf",
       notify => Service['nginx'],
```